# APEX: can't find "Create Mobile Application" Option

Tags: mobile, oracle-apex

According to most tutorials, there should be Mobile Application option on Oracle APEX 5, like this:

[image]

Instead, I get this screen:

[image]

The build is 18.1.0.00.45.

¿Why is this happening?

Answer (score 3):

The mobile theme [has been de-supported in APEX 18.1](https://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-18.1/HTMRN/toc.htm#HTMRN-GUID-C781E563-008D-473E-A1C7-2C00E71E5F03):

> The jQuery Mobile user interface and Mobile Theme - 51 are
> desupported. The last stable version of the jQuery Mobile open source
> library was released on 10/31/2014 and only provides support for
> jQuery versions 1.8 - 1.11 and 2.1, which no longer receive patches.
> Oracle Application Express release 18.1 ships with jQuery 3.2. All new
> application development targeted at mobile devices must be done using
> the responsive Universal Theme. jQuery Mobile will no longer be
> supported in future releases.

The Universal Theme (theme 42) is highly responsive and supports mobile and desktop applications.

Comment: And Kallman on the topic here http://joelkallman.blogspot.com/2017/08/an-important-change-is-coming-for.html